# (Promise loop) _ Make divs highlight one by one with a delay

Tags: javascript, infinite-loop, es6-promise

I'm trying do a small example, in which four divs will highlight one by one in turn. I wanted to do it with loop and promise but the page get into infinite loop. It's definitely something wrong with my promise, But I can't figure it put how should I do it.

```js
'user strict';
var divAr = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
console.log(divAr);
var colors = ['blue', 'red', 'yellow', 'green'];
var i = 0;
while (i < divAr.length) {
  divAr[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
  var promise = new Promise(function(resolve) {
    lightenButton(i);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      resolve(i);
    }, 1500);
  })
  promise.then(function(i) {
    i++;
  });
}

function lightenButton(index) {
  var oldColor = window.getComputedStyle(divAr[index], null)['background-color'];
  var newColor = "";

  function setOldColor() {
    divAr[index].style.backgroundColor = oldColor;
  }

  switch (oldColor) {
    case "rgb(0, 0, 255)":
      newColor = "#9999ff";
      break;
    case "rgb(255, 0, 0)":
      newColor = "#ff9999";
      break;
    case "rgb(255, 255, 0)":
      newColor = "#ffffcc";
      break;
    case "rgb(0, 128, 0)":
      newColor = "#99ff99";
      break;
  }
  divAr[index].style.backgroundColor = newColor;
  setTimeout(setOldColor, 500);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: Grey;
}
div {
  width: 80px;
  height: 55px;
  border: 1px dotted grey;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="1">1</div>
<div id="2">2</div>
<div id="3">3</div>
<div id="4">4</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
var divs = [].slice.call(divAr, 0);
divs.reduce(function(promise, div, index) {
    return promise.then(function() {
        lightenButton(index);
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                resolve();
            }, 1500);
        });
    });
}, Promise.resolve());
```

So, how does it work? Let's first understand the promise chain we need to build:

```
startpromise.then(lightenButtonIndex1).then(lightenButtonIndex2).then(...
```

Reduce iterates over an array of elements and returns the result of the previous function execution. As you can see from the chain illustrated above, we need to have promise returned on each iteration so that we can attach our function to it using `then` method and then return promise again for the next iteration. This exactly what the code is doing. So, we start with `startpromise` which is created with `Promise.resolve()` in the code. And then iterations:

**iteration 1**

```
params (startpromise, div1, index=0)
```

add callback and return promise

```
var lightenButtonIndex1Promise = startpromise.then(lightenButtonIndex1);
return lightenButtonIndex1Promise;
```

**iteration 2**

```
params (lightenButtonIndex1Promise, div2, index=1)
```

add callback and return promise

```
var lightenButtonIndex2Promise = lightenButtonIndex1Promise .then(lightenButtonIndex2);
return lightenButtonIndex2Promise;
```

And so it goes the same way to iteration 4.

---

Here is the version without `reduce`, but it looks cumbersome to me:

```
var promise = Promise.resolve();

for (var i=0; i< divs.length; i++) {
    promise = promise.then((function(index) {
        return function() {
            lightenButton(index);
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    resolve();
                }, 1500);
            });
        }
    })(i));
}
```

---

Here is working example, I modified your `lightenButton` function for demonstration:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var divAr = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

    var divs = [].slice.call(divAr, 0);

    divs.reduce(function (promise, div, index) {
        return promise.then(function () {
            lightenButton(index);
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    resolve();
                }, 1500);
            });
        });
    }, Promise.resolve());

    function lightenButton(index) {
        divs.forEach(function (div, i) {
            if (index === i) {
                divAr[i].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
            } else {
                divAr[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
            }

        });
    }
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: Grey;
}

div {
  width: 80px;
  height: 55px;
  border: 1px dotted grey;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="1">1</div>
<div id="2">2</div>
<div id="3">3</div>
<div id="4">4</div>
```

Comment: thanks, I'll try to understand what you have done, and then modify my example to make it work properly.

Comment: @TarasYaremkiv, hey, did my solution work? Any questions?

Comment: I feel ashamed but could you write this pattern without reduce, cause reduce is complicated function for me + Promise => some kind of magic)

Comment: and yes I've read how reduce works:
array.reduce(function(prevVal, elem, index, array) {  ...
}, initialValue);
prevVal =>  promise;
index   =>  index;
initialValue = > Promise.resolve();

Comment: @TarasYaremkiv, `reduce` is not complicated, let me expand on what's going on, I'll add this information to the question.

Comment: @TarasYaremkiv, added details, please see if it's clear now.

Comment: @TarasYaremkiv, also added the version without `reduce`

Comment: @TarasYaremkiv, did added details help to understand?

Comment: I've made a table like in developer.mozilla.org[reduce] 
if It is right then I understood correct 
[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zHpOKObY65NWr1uAvrIWHgRB-y-1kZV7QUkXgsYbIHQ/pubhtml]

Comment: cool, is there anything else I can add to make my answer acceptable?

Comment: Well if my table is correct
.then(I've understood it right )
.then in my humble opinion it's enough.)

Comment: one question, if it's not hard to tell: I wanted to add function that is executed after reduce is iterated, but at first iteration Promise.resolve() is called, then my function executed but I need the function to be executed after all iteration of reduce have been passed. So I decided to do it with promises like that: var random = function random() { randIndexArr.slice(0, counter + 1).reduce(function (promise, div, index) {..}, Promise.resolve()); }; var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { random(); resolve(); }); promise.then(function () { checkButton(randIndexArr, counter); })

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127566/reducepromises).

Comment: @TarasYaremkiv, `divs.reduce` returns a promise, use it to add you custom function after all promises like so: `divs.reduce(...).then(checkButton)`

Answer (score 3):

This is probably what you're looking for. It needs almost no explanation because `async`/`await` keeps your code stupid simple. Obviously, yes, you will need to [transpile](http://babeljs.io/) your JavaScript in order for this to work in most browsers.

```
const wait = ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));

async function loop (elems, i) {
  elems[i].classList.add('highlight');
  await wait(1000);
  elems[i].classList.remove('highlight');
  await wait(1000);
  return await loop(elems, (i + 1) % elems.length);
}

loop(document.querySelectorAll('div'), 0);
```

Here's a transpiled version which works in the browser. Expand the snippet and see it work :)

```js
'use strict';

var loop = function () {
  var _ref = _asyncToGenerator(regeneratorRuntime.mark(function _callee(elems, i) {
    return regeneratorRuntime.wrap(function _callee$(_context) {
      while (1) {
        switch (_context.prev = _context.next) {
          case 0:
            elems[i].classList.add('highlight');
            _context.next = 3;
            return wait(1000);

          case 3:
            elems[i].classList.remove('highlight');
            _context.next = 6;
            return wait(1000);

          case 6:
            _context.next = 8;
            return loop(elems, (i + 1) % elems.length);

          case 8:
            return _context.abrupt('return', _context.sent);

          case 9:
          case 'end':
            return _context.stop();
        }
      }
    }, _callee, this);
  }));

  return function loop(_x, _x2) {
    return _ref.apply(this, arguments);
  };
}();

function _asyncToGenerator(fn) { return function () { var gen = fn.apply(this, arguments); return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { function step(key, arg) { try { var info = gen[key](arg); var value = info.value; } catch (error) { reject(error); return; } if (info.done) { resolve(value); } else { return Promise.resolve(value).then(function (value) { step("next", value); }, function (err) { step("throw", err); }); } } return step("next"); }); }; }

var wait = function wait(ms) {
  return new Promise(function (r) {
    return setTimeout(r, ms);
  });
};

loop(document.querySelectorAll('.panel'), 0);
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.panel {
  width: 3rem;
  background-color: #eee;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
}

.highlight {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/6.16.0/polyfill.js"></script>
<div class="panel">1</div>
<div class="panel">2</div>
<div class="panel">3</div>
<div class="panel">4</div>
```

Comment: yeah, it's an interesting approach but I don't think it's simpler to understand and requires knowing more advanced features of the language, so "no explanation" is probably replaced with "reading docs" :).

Comment: and it's a part of ES7 spec, which is not going to be implemented soon

Comment: Support for async/await has been added in the Nightly build from the 31st of October (bug #1185106). Great stuff!

Time to start removing those JavaScript transpilers from your experimental projects, and testing native browser support 

Comment: @Maximus I know you put a lot of work into your answer but I honestly can't tell if you're serious about mine being difficult to understand. The loop has 5 lines of code and reads like a story: add a class, wait, remove a class, wait, repeat. If you didn't understand async/await, you might have to look up one thing. Compare that to the conceptual overhead of your answer- converting array-likes to an array, reducing arrays, several manual constructions of Promises, chaining them together, etc. Your code also 5 levels of indentation whereas mine has 1 :/

Comment: @naomik, it's fine with me if it's OK with OP :). Not everyone is using transpilers in their projects, so I assumed that it's better to show it with what current versions of JS support. And as I understood the OP had problems understanding promises, so my answer shows how to do that with promises and explains the inner workings. Anyway, I upvoted since yours is a great solution using ES7 :).